# Disable Quart websocket timeout

Tags: quart

My app uses websockets with quart. I noticed that if the websocket is idle for about 60 seconds the socket automaticslly closes. The quart documentation mentions this is a security feature, but not how to disable it. So how can I disable this idle timeout?

Comment: the problem was nginx not quart